# Is it unusual to edit a model from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Product` model and an `Admin::ProductController`, which is the controller I use in the admin panel to work with these `Product` objects (updating attributes, creating new products, etc)

Is it unusual to perform operations on a model that doesn't have the same prefix as the controller? For example, in the examples I have seen, you have your `Post` model along with your `PostController`, or you have a `Product` model along with the `ProductController`.

Comment: I think it comes down to maintainability and whether a logical relationship exists. I wouldn't expect a `Product` model to be edited from within a `PostsController` directly, or vice versa. However, I would expect that kind of tight coupling, if it exists, to be defined in the model (via relationships), or have behaviour managed with callbacks. For example, it is quite normal to process nested forms that can affect multiple models from within a single controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's perfectly reasonable to modify a Product from Admin::ProductsController.  To me, that relationship is very clear (the controller is doing admin operations on products).  I'd have no problem with this and do it all the time.  You might even have a ProductsController which would manage the public facing actions on Product.

Assuming it's a store, I could also see Admin::ProductsController modifying other models such as ProductSize or ProductOption, etc.  Things very tightly related to Product.

I'd have a problem if it tried to modify Customer or ShippingAddress though.